# native.createnavigator factory is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I am going to design a Drawer navigation in my project.

> I installed that by this command:

```
npm install @react-navigation/drawer
```

Then imported that into `App.js`

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

This is my `package.json` content:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.0",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
"react-native-view-shot": "^3.0.2",
"react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.0",
```

This is my `App.js` content:

```js
const App = () => {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="login">
          <Drawer.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="second" component={SecondPage} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  )
};
```

I should say that I've already created `Login` and `SecondPage` components and declared them in a file named `root.js`

```js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Login, Header, SecondPage, Footer, ThirdPage } from './components/index';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  login: { screen: Login },
  header: { screen: Header },
  second: { screen: SecondPage },
  footer: { screen: Footer },
  third: { screen: ThirdPage }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'login',
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal',
}, {});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

But i'm getting an error  (following screen).

How can i fix this?

[image]

**index.js**

```js
export * from './login';
export * from './header';
export * from './secondpage';
export * from './footer';
export * from './thirdpage';
```

Comment: I had the same issue, re-run - npm install @react-navigation/native solved the problem

Comment: I really appreciate it, Issue has been solved, Do you know how to change Drawer style?I mean backgroundeColor and etc...

Comment: thanks @LironSher update @react-navigation/native worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do now. I think you want to add a drawer Navigator.

Your problem is you have to use one container, but you have two, and createStackNavigator has two parameters, but you have three.

> createStackNavigator(RouteConfigs, StackNavigatorConfig);

I think your navigator structure should be as follows.

**Drawers.js**

```js
export default const Drawers = () => {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  return (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="login">
          <Drawer.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="second" component={SecondPage} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
};
```

**App.js**

```js
import Drawers from "./Drawers"
...

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  login: { screen: Drawers },
  header: { screen: Header },
  second: { screen: SecondPage },
  footer: { screen: Footer },
  third: { screen: ThirdPage }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'login',
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal',
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

**index.js**

```js
import Login from './login';
import Header from './header';
import SecondPage from './secondpage';
import Footer from './footer';
import ThirdPage from './thirdpage';

export { Login, Header, SecondPage, Footer, ThirdPage}
```

OR

> This issue can be a compatibility issue with the version.
>   `React-Navigation` and `StackNavigator` versions must be up to date.

Comment: I tried your solution right now, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Sure this is the index.js content:
```
export * from './login';
export * from './header';
export * from './secondpage';
export * from './footer';
export * from './thirdpage';
```

Comment: Sorry buddy, Please take a look to this one https://imgur.com/a/SMhjl4i

Comment: @roz333 Look at my changed answer. Try changing 'index.js' like this.

Comment: I did but same error occurred, I'm guessing that should be something wrong with drawer syntax, They have recently changed drawer method and there is no any tutorial for new method on internet.

Comment: @roz333 There is no problem in the drawer. I think React-Navigation and StackNavigator should be updated to the latest.

Comment: Yes buddy, I just found out that ,A few hours ago they have updated to version 5, After updating issue was solved.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @roz333  I have completed and corrected my answers. Could you choose my answer, vote and close the question?

Comment: Done, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 52):

You're combining both React Navigation 4 and React Navigation 5 in your project. It's not valid.

React Navigation 4 packages: `react-navigation`, `react-navigation-stack`, `react-navigation-drawer` etc.

React Navigation 5 packages: `@react-navigation/native`, `@react-navigation/stack`, `@react-navigation/drawer` etc.

Follow the official docs and use the correct version and syntax of the packages https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Basically remove your code in `root.js` and create stack navigator like here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install --save @react-navigation/native
```

after that re-run

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

It works for me. I hope, it will work in your case

Answer (score 3):

try install:
yarn add react-navigation-stack

and dependencies:
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

in your routes:
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall @react-navigation/native and reinstall worked for me.

Comment: Are you referring to some other answer here? Your post is phrased like a "Thanks." but I cannot tell what for...

Answer (score -3):

Index.js content

```
export * from './login';
export * from './header';
export * from './secondpage';
export * from './footer';
export * from './thirdpage';
```