# How to fix :Typeerror: (0 , _native.createnavigatorfactory) is not a function. React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Whenever I run my react native app through expo go (iOS) it shows that app-bundling had completed, but a few seconds later it would show the error: typeerror: (0 , _native.createnavigatorfactory) is not a function. I cannot seem to find a way to fix this after scrolling through the internet for hours.
My project is located in GitHub: https://github.com/ShivenKhurana1/MoleDetect

I tried uninstall node_modules and installing it again with npm install
I tried doing `npm install @react-navigation/native`

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] and full error stack trace. Links to off-site resources like Github are not sufficient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [native.createnavigator factory is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087159/native-createnavigator-factory-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.